# Google Drive API and file uploads from the browser

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload a file with the Google Drive api, and I have the metadata correct, and I want to ensure that the actual file contents make it there. I have a simple page setup that looks like this:

```
<div id="upload">
  <h6>File Upload Operations</h6>
  <input type="file" placeholder='file' name='fileToUpload'>
  <button id='uploadFile'>Upload File</button>
</div>
```

and I have a the javascript setup where the user is prompted to sign in first, and then they can upload a file. Here's the code: (currently only uploads the file metadata....)

```
let uploadButton = document.getElementById('uploadFile');
uploadButton.onclick = uploadFile;
const uploadFile = () => {
    let ftu = document.getElementsByName('fileToUpload')[0].files[0];
    console.dir(ftu);
    gapi.client.drive.files.create({
        'content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        uploadType: 'multipart',
        name: ftu.name,
        mimeType: ftu.type,
        fields: 'id, name, kind'
    }).then(response => {
        console.dir(response);
        console.log(`File: ${ftu.name} with MimeType of: ${ftu.type}`);
        //Need code to upload the file contents......
    });
};
```

First, I'm more familiar with the back end, so getting the file in bits from the `<input type='file'>` tag is a bit nebulous for me. On the bright side, the metadata is there. How can I get the file contents up to the api?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So According to some resources I've found in my three day search to get this going, the file simply cannot be uploaded via the gapi client. It must be uploaded through a true REST HTTP call. So let's use `fetch`!

```
const uploadFile = () => {
    //initialize file data from the dom
    let ftu = document.getElementsByName('fileToUpload')[0].files[0];
    let file = new Blob([ftu]); 
    //this is to ensure the file is in a format that can be understood by the API

    gapi.client.drive.files.create({
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        uploadType: 'multipart',
        name: ftu.name,
        mimeType: ftu.type,
        fields: 'id, name, kind, size'
    }).then(apiResponse => {
        fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/${response.result.id}`, {
         method: 'PATCH',
         headers: new Headers({
             'Authorization': `Bearer ${gapi.client.getToken().access_token}`,
              'Content-Type': ftu.type
         }),
         body: file
       }).then(res => console.log(res));

}
```

The Authorization Header is assigned from calling the `gapi.client.getToken().access_token` function, and basically this takes the empty object from the response on the gapi call and calls the `fetch` api to upload the actual bits of the file!

Comment: I tried and "size" is not returned... does it return filesize for you?

Answer (score 2):

In your situation, when you upload a file using `gapi.client.drive.files.create()`, the empty file which has the uploaded metadata is created. If my understanding is correct, how about this workaround? I have experienced the same situation with you. At that time, I used this workaround.

#### Modification points:

- Retrieve access token using gapi.
- File is uploaded using XMLHttpRequest.

#### Modified script:

Please modify the script in `uploadFile()`.

```
let ftu = document.getElementsByName('fileToUpload')[0].files[0];
var metadata = {
    'name': ftu.name,
    'mimeType': ftu.type,
};
var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token; // Here gapi is used for retrieving the access token.
var form = new FormData();
form.append('metadata', new Blob([JSON.stringify(metadata)], {type: 'application/json'}));
form.append('file', ftu);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('post', 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&fields=id,name,kind');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.onload = () => {
    console.log(xhr.response);
};
xhr.send(form);
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, it supposes that Drive API is enabled at API console and the access token can be used for uploading file.
- About fields, you are using `id,name,kind`. So this sample also uses them.

#### Reference:

- [gapi](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js)

If I misunderstand your question or this workaround was not useful for your situation, I'm sorry.

### Edit:

When you want to use `fetch`, how about this sample script?

```
let ftu = document.getElementsByName('fileToUpload')[0].files[0];
var metadata = {
    'name': ftu.name,
    'mimeType': ftu.type,
};
var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token; // Here gapi is used for retrieving the access token.
var form = new FormData();
form.append('metadata', new Blob([JSON.stringify(metadata)], {type: 'application/json'}));
form.append('file', ftu);

fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&fields=id,name,kind', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: new Headers({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken}),
  body: form
}).then((res) => {
  return res.json();
}).then(function(val) {
  console.log(val);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I settled on something similar. I'll post as an answer.

Comment: @Chris Rutherford Thank you for replying. If my answer was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: it's not that it isn't useful, I just feel like using fetch might be a better option going forward. XHR is old, and prone to errors if not used properly. Fetch is the new standard. that's all. Thanks @tanaike

Comment: @Chris Rutherford Thank you for replying. I could understand it. I'm sorry for my poor skill.

Comment: @Chris Rutherford I added a sample script using ``fetch``. Could you please confirm it? In your script, Drive API is used 2 times when a file is uploaded. This script can upload file by one API call. If this was helpful for your situation, I'm glad.

Answer (score 0):

With https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/gapi.client.drive

```
const makeUploadUrl = (fileId: string, params: Record<string, boolean>) => {
  const uploadUrl = new URL(
    `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/${fileId}`
  )

  Object.entries({
    ...params,
    uploadType: 'media',
  }).map(([key, value]) => uploadUrl.searchParams.append(key, `${value}`))

  return uploadUrl
}


  const uploadDriveFile = async ({ file }: { file: File }) => {
    const params = {
      enforceSingleParent: true,
      supportsAllDrives: true,
    }
    
    // create file handle 
    const { result } = await gapi.client.drive.files.create(params, {
      // CAN'T have the upload type here!
      name: file.name,
      mimeType: file.type,
      // any resource params you need...
      driveId: process.env.DRIVE_ID,
      parents: [process.env.FOLDER_ID],
    })

    // post the file data
    await fetch(makeUploadUrl(result.id!, params), {
      method: 'PATCH',
      headers: new Headers({
        Authorization: `Bearer ${gapi.client.getToken().access_token}`,
        'Content-Type': file.type,
      }),
      body: file,
    })

    return result
  })
}
```